# Customizing pseudo-algorithms in algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithm2e

If I have a pseudo-algorithm in Latex that looks like this:

[image]

With source code below.

```
\usepackage[ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
                \DontPrintSemicolon
                $\mathbf{D}_{obs}(f,Nx,Ny,x,y)\leftarrow \mathbf{D}_{obs}(t,Nx,Ny,x,y)$ by 1-D forward FFT\;    
                $\mathbf{D}_0\leftarrow\mathbf{D}_{obs}$\;
                \For{$f\leftarrow 1,2,\dots,F$}{
                    \For{$f\leftarrow 1,2,\dots,F$}{
                        $\mathbf{D}^f_n \leftarrow a_n\mathbf{D}^f_{obs} + (1 - a_n)\mathcal{SF}_{d}\mathbf{D}^f_{n-1} + (1 - \mathcal{S})\mathcal{F}_{d}\mathbf{D}^f_{n-1}$\;
                        \If{$\left\|\mathbf{D}^f_n - \mathbf{D}^f_{n-1}\right\|_F^2\leq\epsilon$}{
                            \textbf{return} $\mathbf{D}^f_n$\;
                        }
                        \textbf{return} $\mathbf{D}^f_{n_{max}}$\;
                    }
                    \textbf{return} $\mathbf{D}_{recovered}$\;
                }
                $\mathbf{D}_{recovered}(t,Nx,Ny,x,y)\leftarrow \mathbf{D}_{recovered}(f,Nx,Ny,x,y)$ by 1-D inverse FFT\;
            
                \caption{Construction Heuristic - Control 4-6}
                \label{algorithm_2}
            \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the bold name "Algorithm 2" into something else, like "Function 2"? Right now it automatically names all algorithm blocks and just adds a number. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169118/rename-algorithm-caption) thread but in this case it just changes ALL algorithm names. Sometimes I want to write "Function" and sometimes "Algorithm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Function}` to change it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
$\mathbf{D}_0\leftarrow\mathbf{D}_{obs}$
\caption{Construction Heuristic - Control 4-6}
\label{algorithm_2}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Function}
$\mathbf{D}_0\leftarrow\mathbf{D}_{obs}$
\caption{Construction Heuristic - Control 4-6}
\label{algorithm_2}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
$\mathbf{D}_0\leftarrow\mathbf{D}_{obs}$
\caption{Construction Heuristic - Control 4-6}
\label{algorithm_2}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I suppress the numbers? For example if I only want to write 'Algorithm' and not 'Algorithm 1' ?

Comment: @Parseval Add `\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}\addtocounter{algocf}{-1}` in `algorithm` environment.

Comment: You're the MVP. Thanks!